# Console RPG - show cycle optimization

Tags: c#, performance, console

I have this RPG game and this has elements such as the map, the monsters and the items. The monsters and the items are stored in `List`s and every time I want to show the map around the player, I have to check if the element is within the bounds of the camera.

```
public void ShowCamera()
    {
        int size = cameraSize/2;
        int topY = player.GetY() - size, bottomY = player.GetY() + size, topX = player.GetX() - size, bottomX = player.GetX() + size;
        int setX = 0, setY = 0;

        //Print Map
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        for (int i = topX; i < bottomX; i++)
        {
            for (int j = topY; j < bottomY; j++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(setY,setX);
                Console.Write(map[i, j]);
                if (monstros.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    foreach (var elem in monstros)
                    {
                        if (elem.ReX() == i && elem.ReY() == j)
                        {
                            Console.SetCursorPosition(setY, setX);
                            Console.Write(elem);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    foreach (var elem in items)
                    {
                        if (elem.ReX() == i && elem.ReY() == j)
                        {
                            Console.SetCursorPosition(setY, setX);
                            Console.Write(elem);
                        }
                    }
                }
                setY++;
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            setY = 0;
            setX++;
        }
```

So, this works but it is very unoptimized and flickers a lot. I was wondering if there's a way to improve this cycle in any way.

Comment: What are `monstros` and `items`? What is `map`?

Comment: Those are the game elements. Monstros = monsters, items = items (swords and stuff),  map is my 2d array that contains the walls.

Comment: I understand, but we'd need to know what they are code-wise, because for instance looping though all elements of `monstros` just to find an appropriate one inside two `for` loops seems like a massive overhead. There's some optimization possible there IMHO, but it's impossible to know unless you show us the relevant code.

Comment: Well, the `monstros` code is simply it's appeareance, an X and a Y. That's pretty much what they are. That applies for the items aswell.

Comment: 1) Could you keep your lists sorted by coordinate, or sort them?  2) What's flickering, the whole screen or only  the parts where there are items and monsters?   I notice you always draw the background even when there is a monster.  If you only drew one thing per coordinate, it would eliminate flicker for those areas.  However, if the whole screen flickers, it may be because the function is just too slow. 3) How big is your screen, and how many monsters and items do you typically have?

Answer (score 6):

**Performance**

The main problem seems to be that you're checking each monster and item *for each console position*. If `cameraSize` is 80, that means you're checking each monster and item 80 x 80 = 6400 times.

Just draw the map first, and *then* loop through your monsters and items (once) and draw them if they're within view.

**Other notes**

You're using a lot of getter methods: `GetX()`, `GetY()`, `ReX()`, `ReY()`. In C# properties are normally used instead of getter/setter methods.

`ReX` and `ReY` are not very descriptive names. Obviously we're dealing with coordinates here, but what does that `Re` prefix mean?

Since you're dealing with 2D coordinates quite frequently, it could be useful to create a separate `Position` class for that, with `X` and `Y` properties and perhaps some overloaded operators (`+`, `-`) and utility methods (`int DistanceTo(Position other)`, and so on).

Calling `Console.Write(elem)` invokes elem's `ToString` method. Personally I'd give those monster and item classes a `public char Appearance { get; private set; }` property, and turn that write call into `Console.Write(elem.Appearance)`, to make it more obvious what's going on, and so I don't have to abuse a `ToString` method.

**Monstro and Item class**

*These notes refer to the classes you posted in the chat:*

`new Random()` gives you a pseudorandom number generator that's seeded based on the current time. Because each monster has its own `Random` instance, they will likely move in the exact same way if you create multiple monster instances at the same time (or close enough).

Your movement code can be simplified: if you use a `offsetX` and `offsetY` variable, which are set based on the chosen direction, then you don't need that switch-case statement anymore.

Making `Item` responsible for its own placement is quite inflexible. Just give its constructor an x and y parameter, and let the map-generating/loading code figure out where to place items.

Randomly picking spots until you find an empty one should work just fine if there's plenty of space, but large maps with few empty spots will cause a lot of retries. It'll even loop indefinitely if there is no empty spot available.

`SetPickedUp` can be simplified to `pickedUp = argPickedUp`. Or just use a property instead.

`Map.CheckTile` is not a very descriptive name. `Map.IsTileEmpty` is more obvious.

You don't need those `StringBuilder`s in your `ToString` methods. Just return `appearance.ToString()` or `GetType().Name` directly.

**More notes**

Making `Item` and `Monstro` abstract implies that you've got several classes that inherit from them. I assume that each different item has a class of its own? That makes sense if different items actually have different behavior, but if they only have different stats, then a single `Item` class is sufficient. Since `Item` has an `attack`, `defense`, `health` and `rarity` field, it can already be used for a variety of different items: weapons (attack), armor (defense), health potions (health).

In larger games, such data is often stored in csv or Excel files, which makes it easy for game-designers to adjust items without the help of a programmer. In your case that's probably not worth the effort, but you can still create a 'table' of item data in code. For a one-man project that's just as easy to modify, and still saves you a ton of useless classes:

```
var itemBlueprints = Dictionary<string, Item> {
    { "Sword", new Item(5, 0, 0, 0.05, '|') },
    { "Shield", new Item(0, 2, 0, 0.08, 'o') },
    { "Potion", new Item(0, 0, 5, 0.12, '+') },
};
```

You'll want to add a `Name` property to the `Item` class so you can still determine an item's name (the type name no longer tells you what it is). That's more flexible than using a type name anyway.

The above code could be made a little more readable by using optional and named parameters:

```
new Item("Sword", attack: 5, rarity: 0.05, appearance: '|');
new Item("Shield", defense: 2, rarity: 0.08, appearance: 'o');
```

Comment: There is also `System.Windows.Point` and `System.Drawing.Point` classes, which already support some common math operators out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

it appears that you are duplicating code here

> ```
> if (monstros.Count > 0)
> {
>     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
>     foreach (var elem in monstros)
>     {
>         if (elem.ReX() == i && elem.ReY() == j)
>         {
>             Console.SetCursorPosition(setY, setX);
>             Console.Write(elem);
>         }
>     }
> }
> if (items.Count > 0)
> {
>     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
>     foreach (var elem in items)
>     {
>         if (elem.ReX() == i && elem.ReY() == j)
>         {
>             Console.SetCursorPosition(setY, setX);
>             Console.Write(elem);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I think that this could be done with a method and then called for either `items` or `monstros`

Maybe a method similar to this

```
public void DrawSprite(List<object> sprite, int x, int y, int newX, int newY)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    foreach (var element in sprite)
    {
        if (element.Rex() == x && element.ReY() == y)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(newY, newX);
            Console.Write(element);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the term `sprite` but you can name it whatever you like.

I also used a list of type `object` but I assume that you have an interface or type that encompasses the *items* and *monsters* that you could use in its place.

I removed the check for whether or not there are any elements in the list because in a foreach statement if there are no objects in the container that you are enumerating it just won't enumerate, so it was really unnecessary.

I would use some Linq as well, but I don't know exactly how your types work, but this code would be a lot simpler using Linq for the foreach statements.

This is a simple method call now.

```
DrawSprite(monstros, x, y, setX, setY);
DrawSprite(items, x, y, setX, setY);
```

The only thing that I don't like about this is the amount of parameters that we are sending to the method,  I would recommend creating an XY point class and using points instead of `variableX` and `variableY`, this will make your code a lot cleaner, among other things.

---

Now, your code should look like this

```
public void ShowCamera()
{
    var monstros = new List<bool>();
    int size = cameraSize/2;
    int topY = player.GetY() - size,
        bottomY = player.GetY() + size,
        topX = player.GetX() - size,
        bottomX = player.GetX() + size;
    int setX = 0, setY = 0;

    //Print Map
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
    for (int x = topX; x < bottomX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = topY; y < bottomY; y++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(setY, setX);
            Console.Write(map[x, y]);

            DrawSprite(monstros, x, y, setX, setY);
            DrawSprite(items, x, y, setX, setY);

            setY++;
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        setY = 0;
        setX++;
    }
}

public void DrawSprite(List<object> sprite, int x, int y, int newX, int newY)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    foreach (var element in sprite)
    {
        if (element.Rex() == x && element.ReY() == y)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(newY, newX);
            Console.Write(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's a few things to note on your answer tho. First of all, nothing is random in the way I did things.
The `i` and `j` are not equal to `setX` and `setY`. The i and j correspond to the bounds of the camera considering my player's position and the setX and setY equal to that representation but starting on (0,0).
Then the `DrawSprite` method will not work because the argument `List<object> sprite` does not know `.ReX()` or `.ReY()` exist.

Comment: I know that you will need to replace the object type in the list declaration, that was given in my review.

Comment: @EpaXapate I removed the removal of the `setX` and `setY`, what you said makes sense and I should have seen it in your code.

Comment: Therefore this method cannot help me.

Comment: @EpaXapate, what do you mean it can't help you? it removes duplication of code.

Comment: because there is no way for the program to know if it's the correct type of object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41820/discussion-between-malachi-and-epaxapate).

Comment: to further reduce code since they are only enumerating through elements remove check of any elements

Answer (score 0):

@Pieter gives great advice on performance (and other things).

I would like to add that ShowCamera() appears to deal with drawing map and not with showing some camera to somebody, thus I suggest renaming this method.

Eventually, you may get something like this:

```
    public void DrawMap()
    {
        DrawEmptyMap();

        DrawMonsters();
        DrawItems();
    }
```

DrawMonsters() and DrawItems() may have logic like this:

```
    private void DrawMonsters()
    {
        var visibleMonsters = this.monstros.Select(m => this.IsVisible(m));

        foreach (var monster in visibleMonsters)
        {
            monster.Draw();
        }
    }
```

Here I assume that you store all the map highlights (top points, bottom points...) somewhere in the class. IsVisible() and Draw() methods do some trivial job on comparing coordinates. Further details depend on how you are going to implement inheritance of your sprites and storing their coordinates.

Note also to [write only one var declaration per line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx#Anchor_1).